# How do I put a string into a system process?

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

Here is my code:

```
string TB10 = "2018";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"c:\E&I Asset Records\R&R Dropbox\SouthWest"+ TB10;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Can anyone tell me how to put the string TB10 into the code without it throwing an error?

Comment: What error does it throw? Please include complete error message in your question.

Comment: It could be that `c:\E&I Asset Records\R&R Dropbox\SouthWest2018` is a directory, not a file. Or maybe you forget to append `.exe` to the string.